# Error accessing system property in spring applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

I want to set my db file location as part of system variable which shall be provided at time of starting application.
I want to access this system property in `applicationContext.xml` for which I have tried to use `#{systemProperties['db.properties']}`in `applicationContext.xml.`

I have defined propertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean in 2 following ways specifying value for property "locations" in 2 different ways:

## Case 1 #:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">

             <value>file://"#{systemProperties['db.properties']}"</value>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
         <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

## dataSource bean #:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
        destroy-method="close"> 
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/> 
     <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
     <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
     <property name="password" value="${db.pwd}"/>
</bean>
```

## Case 2 #:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">

            <value>file://${DB_CONF}/test/db.properties</value>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
         <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

If I use the value of property locations as in case 2 instead of 
"#{systemProperties['db.properties']}"  application works perfectly OK.
In the case 1, I try to access the same  properties file from same location as a System property but application does not work with error as follows:

## Stack Trace

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL '${db.url}'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 136 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
```

Comment: only change the property reader other code working fine

Answer (score 0):

Here you find how to read properties file using xml

```
<bean id="propertyBean"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
             <!-- This will find you file inside system classpath -->
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <!-- or you pass the whole path -->
            <!--<value>file:///opt/application.properties</value> -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the error.The culprit was double quotes.
Using  file://#{systemProperties['db.properties']} instead of  file://"#{systemProperties['db.properties']}" resolved the issue.